# How to list my application on file manager's open with?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to open a file with my application. Added this intent filter, but file manager is not listing to my app. The file is a custom text file with type of .tdr. What am I doing wrong ?

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="file/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Also tried mime type "*/*"
I have multiple intent filters, this is one of them.

Comment: Try "text/*"...

Comment: Did not work...

Comment: `a custom text file with type of .tdr.` You mean: with a .tdr extension. Well that is the problem. Make it .txt.

Comment: `but file manager not listing my app.` Then which apps were listed instead?

Comment: Every other app except my app. Telegram Xplore text and image viewer , phone ...

Comment: Use `"*/*"` for all files.

Comment: Tried, it does nothing .when I press share, my app is in the list but not in open with list

Comment: For open with you need ACTION_VIEW. ACTION_SEND is for share.

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"
                      android:scheme="text"/>
            </intent-filter>

is this correct for action view ?
tried this but nothing appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as "blackapps" said i had to use android.intent.action.VIEW

this now works:

```html
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
   <data android:mimeType="*/*"
         android:scheme="file"/>
</intent-filter>
```